# PHP - select first 40 words of a message retrieved with Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook PHP SDK to display my fan page feeds on my website. However the feeds are too long so I need to select only the 40 first word. 
After some research I found that this code is what I need but because I don't know how to insert it in my php.

```
implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $post['message'], 0, 40));
```

My php is accessing facebook with the graph API and here is my php:

```
    <?php

    echo "<div class=\"fb-feed\">";
    foreach ($pagefeed['data'] as $post) {


    if ($post['type'] == 'link') {

    echo "<p>" . $post['message'] . "</p>";

    }

    echo "</div>"; // close fb-update div

    $i++; // add 1 to the counter if our condition for $post['type'] is met
    }

    } // end the foreach statement

    ?>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I hope all answerers realize there's a `)` missing...

Comment: @jeroen Your hopes have been destroyed.

Comment: @AlexandruG. Yep, no winner today :-(

Comment: Why did I get a downvote ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question within the scope of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - **Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change**

```
echo "<p>" . $post['message'] . "</p>";
```

**To**

```
echo "<p>" . implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $post['message']), 0, 40)) . "</p>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but I am getting an error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'. Any Idea?

Comment: Try now, was missing one closing )

Comment: You might want to check the manual on `explode`.

Comment: Wrong place :D Thanks @jeroen

Comment: Thanks Joni! I am getting another error now. I am on joomla, using jumi to store my php. `Warning: explode() expects at most 3 parameters, 4 given in modules/mod_jumi/tmpl/default.php(13) : eval()'d code on line 66` and this one `Warning: array_slice() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in modules/mod_jumi/tmpl/default.php(13) : eval()'d code on line 66` and `Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in àmodules/mod_jumi/tmpl/default.php(13) : eval()'d code on line 66`. I am looking into it.

Comment: Oh hey did you see I accidentally placed the ) in wrong place at first, but fixed it after jeroen noticed it. It should now be working

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen your update! Thanks a lot you did it! Yeehaa!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work I guess:

```
<?php


$message = "";
foreach ($pagefeed['data'] as $post) {


if ($post['type'] == 'link') {
    $message += implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $post['message'], 0, 40));
}

$i++; // add 1 to the counter if our condition for $post['type'] is met
}

} // end the foreach statement
echo "<div class=\"fb-feed\">";
echo $message;
echo "</div>"; // close fb-update div

?>
```